# NiFi List File Processor - Interrupt run schedule and restart the run schedule when new incoming file

Tags: apache-nifi

**Scenario:**

1. I have a List File Processor looking out for incoming file ("file 1"). I scheduled it to start picking up the "file 1" 20s after the "file 1" is downloaded.
2. Let assume that the List File Processor noticed the incoming "file 1" and started the delay 20 sec before picking the "file 1".
3. In the middle of 20 sec delay, there is an new incoming file ("file 2") noticed by the List File Processor.
4. List File Processor will be interrupt and reset the 20 sec schedule time when ("file 2") appear within the previous 20 sec delay

**Could the List File Processor in the middle of 20 sec delay be interrupt and restart the initial delay? Appreciate help with explanation and example.**

Thanks.

Comment: Execution of `ListFile`  is scheduled by setting `Run Schedule`. No need to interrupt the delay, if any files are missing from the first scheduled execution, those will be listed on the subsequent schedules. Are you facing any issues while listing files?

Comment: Hi @VikramsinhShinde,  
Yes I am facing an issues. I have a varies number of files could be (2 or 3 or n). The total downloaded files size into the monitor folder by List File processor are more than 5GB.
 
I don think I am able to predict the estimated run schedule as there are varies number of files to be downloaded. Leads to varies download time. 

In my scenario, I do not want the List File processor to listed all the files on the first scheduled execution and some files will be listed on subsequent scheduled execution.

Comment: @VikramsinhShinde 

Currently I don think I am able to set the Run Schedule Time as download time varies. I would like to ask for advise with explanation and example on how could I list all the files at one and only schedule execution and not subsequent schedule execution?

Even with the schedule time set, I would like to listed all the files at one and only schedule execution and not subsequent schedule execution?

Comment: NiFi is a real-time data ingestion platform and the functionality provided by ListFile is by design and I think it is not fit for your use case. The information you have provided highlights concerns such as - How ListFile is supposed to know that all the files have been downloaded, available for listing and it has to start listing? What is the measure for `all` files, it could be one file or several files? The only solution I can think of is either set `Run Schedule` duration high enough eg. once a day or whenever you are in need of data you can manually start/stop the `ListFile`